# Java char contains value > 255?

Tags: java, char

I get a char array from a socket :

```
char[] cbuf = new char[3];
inputStream.read(cbuf, 0, 3); // read 3 chars in buffer "cbuf", offset = 0
```

Then when I print that :

```
System.out.println("r:"+(int)cbuf[0]+" g:"+(int)cbuf[1]+" b:"+(int)cbuf[2]);
```

I get at some point :

```
...
r:82 g:232 b:250
r:82 g:232 b:250
r:66 g:233 b:8224
```

The **8224** value is way more than **255**, how can a char contain this value ???

Thank you

Comment: The problem is that you're reading the data through a 'Reader' instead of an 'InputStream'. A Reader translates the bytes into characters using an encoding, which in your case is probably windows-1252.  See my answer below.

Comment: I assume you come from a C background where the sizeof(char) == sizeof(byte), however even in C I would suggest you use unsigned byte as the values of r/g/b are not characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `char` primitive in Java in 16 bits wide, to accommodate characters outside the standard ASCII range, using [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

It looks like you're trying to store RGB values in a `char[3]`. May I suggest a `byte[3]`, or [java.awt.Color](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)?

```
Color c = new Color(255, 255, 240);
```

Comment: @sje397: No, I mean [Modified UTF-8 and CESU-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#UTF-8_derivations).

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: No, you mean UTF-16. It's true that Java also uses modified UTF-8, but not for the char type: it simply can't because that would require more than 16 bits for any character >= U+0800. Java 1.4 and earlier uses UCS-2, Java 1.5 switched to UTF-16.

Comment: @Stephen, @Michael: of course you're right - logically, it has to be so. I've edited my answer.

Comment: The hint to use chars instead of bytes is right, however I don't see how `java.awt.Color` is supposed to help him with the task of actually reading the rgb values from the stream.

Comment: @Grodriguez: I imagine that the OP is printing the color channel values just to see what they are, or as a debugging step. He may want to do something with the channels later, and that something may be easier if he's handling the values using idiomatic Java.

Comment: That's right, however the way you phrased it is somewhat misleading -- "`byte[3]` or `java.awt.Color`". One thing is directly related to this problem, the other a 'suggestion that may be useful later.'

Comment: @Grodriguez: Something wrong with "a suggestion that may be useful later" (especially when I explicitly call it out as a suggestion)?

Comment: Nothing more than what I already explained in my comment above.

Comment: Ooops it seems like byte in java is signed, so when I try to create the color object, I have values < 0 and this throws an exception. How can I force the values to be unsigned ?

Answer (score 7):

There is no `read(char[], int, int)` method on [InputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).  You must be calling that on a [Reader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) sub-class (such as [InputStreamReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html)).  [InputStreamReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) automatically converts bytes to characters using the platform default character encoding which in your case looks like it's [windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows1252).

The character you received, 8224 is Unicode character [U+2020 Dagger '†'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2020/index.htm). This was probably translated from byte 0x86 (134) using the windows-1252 character encoding.

If you're reading a file containing stuff that isn't text, you need to make sure that you don't read it with a subclass of [Reader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) but use a subclass of [InputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) instead.  Alternatively, you can use an [InputStreamReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) and specify a character encoding like [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) that will map every byte to a char with the same numeric value.

Comment: To clarify:   Find where variable "inputStream" [sic] is created; most likely its created using socket.getInputStream().  Remove the wrapped InputStreamReader and make sure that the raw InputStream is used. Read into a byte[] instead.   Make sure that the protocol actually sends 3 bytes in the order you think;  And finally, consider using Color.

Comment: Thanks +1. (I had no idea char was 16 bits, so I accepted the other answer)

Answer (score 5):

The [`char` type in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) is 16-bit.

If you are looking for an 8 bit datatype consider using `byte`.

Comment: Not if you use characters outside the BMP.  What `char` contains is UTF-16 code units.

Answer (score 2):

As people have already pointed out, you want to read bytes, not chars (chars are 16 bits in Java), and make sure you are actually using an `InputStream` and not a `Reader`.

I also want to point out something that is not directly related to your question: When calling `InputStream.read(byte[])` or `InputStream.read(byte[], int, int)` to read several bytes, do not assume that all requested bytes have been read upon return. The call to `read` may return as soon as **some** bytes are available. You should always check the return value to find out how many bytes have actually been read.

The same applies to the `read` methods in `Reader`.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses UTF (not ASCII) to store chars, UTF is 16-bits long so it can contain values up to 65.535.

Comment: Not entirely true. UTF-16 is 16 bits 'long'. UTF-8 is 8 bits 'long'. Although this is a flexible use of the word 'long' as each can have longer sequences for certain code points.

Comment: JLS 3.1: "...The Java programming language represents text in sequences of 16-bit code units, using the UTF-16 encoding. ..."   http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#248597

Answer (score 0):

Chars are unsigned 16bit ints in Java. Though technically, if you are receiving values from untrusted bytecode you must be prepared to deal with arbitrary 32bit values as the JVM doesn't do any verification of integer argument ranges.